# Closed-form formula for inverse of this function

Tags: calculus, expected-value

I need to find the inverse of the expected value of the continuous Bernoulli distribution. Here is the formula:

$$
\frac{x}{2x-1}  + \frac{1}{2\tanh^{-1}(1-2x)}
$$

Is there a simple closed-form formula for inverse of this function?

Comment: [I doubt it.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+of+%28x%2F%282x-1%29%2B1%2F%282*tanh%281-2x%29%29)

Comment: @EricTowers, I plotted the function, and seems increasing, and so injective, where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @enzotib : I see one problem: I fat-fingered the function so was looking at the wrong plot.  Sorry.

Comment: @K.defaoite  You plotted the wrong function. The denominator in the second term is "Arctanh" but you entered  "tanh" instead.

Comment: [Ok.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+of+%28x%2F%282x-1%29%2B1%2F%282*arctanh%281-2x%29%29)

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is the function term of an [elementary function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function).
This function doesn't have [partial inverses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Partial_inverses) that are elementary functions.

$$\text{arctanh}(x)=\frac{1}{2}\,\ln(x+1)-\frac{1}{2}\,\ln(1-x)$$

$$\frac{x}{2\,x-1}-\frac{1}{2\,\text{arctanh}(2\,x-1)}$$

$$\frac{x}{2\,x-1}-\frac{1}{2\,(\frac{1}{2}\,\ln(2\,x)-\frac{1}{2}\,\ln(2-2\,x))}$$

$${\frac{-x\ln(x)+x\ln(1-x)+2\,x-1}{(2\,x-1)(-\ln(x)+\ln(1-x))}}$$

This is the function term of an elementary function of $x$. It's the function term of an algebraic function over the algebraic numbers of $x$, $\ln(x)$ and $\ln(1-x)$. If [Schanuel's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_conjecture) is true, the [transcendence degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendence_degree) of $\{x,\ln(x),\ln(1-x)\}$ over the algebraic numbers is 3. We cannot simplify the algebraic term of the three indeterminates to one with less than 3 indeterminates therefore. With help of the theorem in [Ritt 1925], that is proved also in [Risch 1979], we can conclude that the mentioned elementary function doesn't have partial inverses that are elementary functions.
$\ $

[[Risch 1979] Risch, R. H.: Algebraic Properties of the Elementary Functions of Analysis. Amer. J. Math. 101 (1979) (4) 743-759](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2373917?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)

[[Ritt 1925] Ritt, J. F.: Elementary functions and their inverses. Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 27 (1925) (1) 68-90](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1925-027-01/S0002-9947-1925-1501299-9/)